# Unable to properly set custom headers using angular

Tags: .net, angularjs, http-headers, cors

I have an .net WebAPI project running on IIS with CORS enabled. This project has an authorization handler which check for a header named "Token" in every request, for now it only checks if it has a string value.

In my API call with angular, I'm using the following line to add headers. I took this from the angular documentation

> $http.defaults.headers.common['Token'] = 'C3POR2D2';

Raw data from fiddler for the API is as follows.

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:81/api/Sample/GetSubordinateRolesForUser/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:81
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/40.0.2214.45 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, token
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost/Account/Login
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

In here 'token' appears as a value under Access-Control-Request-Headers. This is causing my authorization handler to return a 403 Forbidden, as it is expecting the header 'Token' with some string value.

Following is the response raw data

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Token
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Date: Wed, 07 Jan 2015 11:28:43 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: The above request is OK. The browser first uses OPTIONS method to check if the browser is allowed to access the url http://localhost:81/api/Sample/GetSubordinateRolesForUser/1 with the given headers. Your problem is most likely a CORS issue.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the response headers, it seems that CORS is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

use this. i also face the similar issues

```
function getSettings(requestData) {
    return {
        url: requestData.url,
        dataType: requestData.dataType || "json",
        data: requestData.data || {},
        headers: requestData.headers || {
            "accept": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            'Authorization': requestData.token
        },
        async: requestData.async || "false",
        cache: requestData.cache || "false",
        success: requestData.success || {},
        error: requestData.error || {},
        complete: requestData.complete || {},
        fail: requestData.fail || {}
    };
}
```

and call this like this way

```
    var requestData = {
        url: 'your API end point',
        data: project,
        token: yourtoken
    };

    var settings = getSettings(requestData);
    settings.method = "POST"; //Your request
    return $http(settings);
```

and remove $http.defaults.headers.common['Token'] = 'C3POR2D2';